# Is there a differentiable function that tends to ∞ at some point such that its derivative doesn't tend to ±∞ at that point?

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a differentiable function $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}{f(x) = \infty}$.

Do we necessarily have $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}{f'(x) = -\infty}$?

I thought this had to be true until I started trying to prove it using Lagrange's theorem and realized it doesn't work. $f'$ will be unbounded, since the average rate of change of $f$ over $(x,b)$ will tend to -$\infty$ as $x$ tends to $a$ from the right. But we nonetheless could have $f'$ reach as low as we want and return to $0$ (for example) on infinitesimally small intervals.

For example the function $\frac{1}{sin(\frac{1}{x})^2}$ behaves this way — it is unbounded but doesn't tend to $\infty$ as $x$ tends to $0$. So I suppose the antiderivative of some function of this type could tend to $\infty$?

Any insight on why this is possible/impossible is appreciated :)

Comment: The limit need not exist. Think of a function whose graph resembles an  infinity tall staircase.

Comment: Something like $-\ln x +\sin(1/x)$ should work.

Comment: Thank you! Could you let me know the intuition behind how you found that function? I'm a beginner calc student

Comment: Well, just take a function that tends to infinity and add "wiggles" to it ($\sin(1/x)$). Need to be careful, though, that the wiggles are not  dampened out.

Comment: The simplest example would be ${1\over x}-\sin{1\over x}.$ It certainly satisfies $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\infty.$ Moreover $f'(x)=-{1\over x^2}+{1\over x^2}\cos{1\over x}.$ The derivative vanishes at $x=(2\pi n)^{-1}.$

Answer (score 0):

Well if there was a finite $L$ s.t. $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f'(x) = L$, then there is a $\epsilon >0$ s.t. $|f'|$ is bounded in $(a,a+\epsilon]$ and then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x) = f(a+\epsilon)-\int_a^{a+\epsilon} f'(x)dx \leq f(a+\epsilon) + \sup_{x\in (a,a+\epsilon]}|f'(x)|\cdot \epsilon \lneq \infty
\end{align*}

Comment: Sure but if there isn't any limit, finite or infinite, of $f'(x)$ and $f'(x)$ is unbounded from below but oscillates between 0 and increasingly small numbers, with oscillations getting more and more frequent (like with $sin(\frac{1}{x})$?